# How to use a Python virtual environment in Qt Creator?

Tags: python, qt-creator

I am using Ubuntu and I want to use Qt Creator to make a Python application.
Let's say I have an environment called `tf-n`, having all my needed libraries, and I want to use it for my Qt Project. I already have installed `PySide6` based on [this document](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/quickstart.html).

I have also done [the steps in this document](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-language-servers.html) to add a language server. But when I run the project from Qt Creator, it attempts to use a default Python executable.

The executable I am trying to use: `/home/sahand/anaconda3/envs/tf-n/bin/python`

The error I get: `/home/sahand/anaconda3/bin/python exited with code 1`

Also, here is how I set the environment:
Qt Creator Language Client Setting:
[image: Qt Creator Language Client Setting]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you try to run these Pythons directly in console `/home/sahand/anaconda3/envs/tf-n/bin/python` and `/home/sahand/anaconda3/bin/python` - maybe it gives you more information.